# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in solr while ajax call

Tags: jquery, solr

I am trying to store data in the solr server but the page is showing error

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="Include/JS/JqueryPlugin/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function save() {
        try {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://192.168.10.113:8080/solr/update/json?commit=true",
                data: { "add": { "doc": { "id": "222222", "name": "Ruby on Trails" } } },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                crossDomain: true,
                jsonp: 'json.wrf'
            });
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="button" onclick="save()" value="Submit" />
</body>
</html>
```

how to over come from this problem.
I searched on google and found that syntax error in the html page or in js page .

But in my case there no error i checked.

please help to solve this error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: My server is in different domain so i am sending data using jsonp.
while fetching data from server i am doing like above so i did here.

Comment: What do you see in Firebug's Network tab?

Comment: you can see my problem
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/195/errormiz.png/

Comment: Your server is sending XML, not JSONP.

Comment: how to solve this issue?
server is not my control .
how to fix this issue ??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18937/discussion-between-bhagirathi-and-slaks)

Comment: Yes my server is sending XML.
how to set the server so that server will send json object.
or any other method to solve the error.